# Two subselect into "IN" (oracle, sql)

Tags: sql, oracle12c, sql-in

How can I use into **"IN"** two subselect?

I have now:

```
select colA, colB from table1 where colC in
                 (select T1 from tableT1 where colx = 'Y')
                 and ColD = 'Y';
```

I need too also that *colC* will be into second subselect:

```
select colA, colB from table1 where colC in
                 ((select T1 from tableT1 where colx = 'Y')
                  or
                 (select T2 from tableT2 where colx = 'Y'))
                 and ColD = 'Y';
```

It's possible to do that? or maybe some union?

Comment: `colC in <first-sub-select> or colC in <second-sub-select>`

Comment: Please rephrase your question providing more context, and a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `union`:

```
where colC in
(
    select T1 from tableT1 where colx = 'Y'
    union
    select T2 from tableT2 where colx = 'Y'
)
and ColD = 'Y'
```

Comment: Would it be more efficient to use `UNION ALL`?

Comment: The OP asked "I need too also that colC will be into second subselect" - the OP's language is not entirely clear but this will give "colC IN (first_subselect) OR colC IN ( second_subselect)" whereas I read the OP's question as wanting "colC IN (first_subselect) AND colC IN ( second_subselect)".

Comment: @MT0: if it has to be in both subsets, you could use `intersect` instead of `union`. Agree that `union all` would be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you @Andomar

Answer (score 1):

> I need too also that colC will be into second subselect:

If you need it to be in both tables then you can do:

```
select colA, colB
from   table1
where  colC in ( select T1 from tableT1 where colx = 'Y' )
AND    colC in ( select T2 from tableT2 where colx = 'Y' )
AND    ColD = 'Y';
```

If you need it to be in one or the other (or both) tables then you can do:

```
select colA, colB
from   table1
where  (  colC in ( select T1 from tableT1 where colx = 'Y' )
       OR colC in ( select T2 from tableT2 where colx = 'Y' )
       )
AND    ColD = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select colA, colB from 
                 ((select T1 as T, ColA,colB from tableT1 where colx = 'Y')
                  Union
                 (select  T2 as T, ColA,colB from tableT2 where colx = 'Y'))  as table1 where table1.T = ColC
                 and ColD = 'Y';
```

I assume Colc is a value not a column as you cannot use column name in where cause to search through value like you mentioned in your question